# divisors count sum gives time consuming issue

Tags: c, division

I want to write divisors of all numbers between 1,...,n for a given n and then out the number of them and the sum of them.
For example:
For 3:
1,1,2,1,3
Output is 5, 8
I tried to get every j in range 1,n and then count the number of divisors by using the below code
but the it is not efficient because of time consuming.

```
int count=0;
int sum=0;
for(int j=1,j<=n,j++){
    for(int i=1,i<=j,i++){
        if(j%i==0){
            count+=1;
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Write your complete code. That snippet doesn’t show anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You would need to show a bit more to allow any evaluation of your algorithm. Please edit your question to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I hope this new edit of mine helps

Comment: Your question states you want to “**write** divisors of all numbers” and you want to “**out** the number of them and the sum of them”. If you want to write all the divisors, there is no shortcut; each one has to be written to output. Maybe this text just meant conceptually we are thinking about all the divisors, not actually writing them to output. But the sample code contains no output operations at all, so it does not clarify the matter. Edit the question to explain clearly what should be output and what should not be output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a famous problem so should have been asked before.
Instead of getting each number and then finding its divisors,
you can simply count how many numbers are multiple of each number in that range.

---

that is [n/i].
so each number i in {1,...,n} appears [n/i] times.
what remains for counting the number of them is summing this for
all i in the range and summing i*[n/i] for the sum.
This code does what you want:

---

Instead of getting each number and then finding its divisors,
you can simply count how many numbers are multiple of each number in that range.
that is [n/i].
so each number i in {1,...,n} appears [n/i] times.
what remains for counting the number of them is summing this for
all i in the range and summing i*[n/i] for the sum.
This code does what you want:

```
int main(){
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);

int nums=0;
int sums=0;
for (int i=1; i<n+1;i++){
    nums = nums + (n/i);
}

for (int i=1; i<n+1; i++){
    sums = sums + (i* (n/i));

}
printf("%d %d",nums, sums);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but doesn't i*(n/i) gives us n? So we get sums= n*n?

Comment: No. Because n and i are integers so (n/i) is like casting to int, it means that the answer is actually the ceiling of n divided by i. which is what we want

Comment: @Whiterose: For integer types `n` and `i`, `n/i` gives the result of truncating `n`/`i` to zero. For positive `n` and `i`, this gives the floor of `n`/`i`, not the ceiling.